# Android - m3u8 video streaming

Tags: android, stream, vlc

I am streaming live video in my app. I have a .m3u8 link, which works perfectly in vlc player. But when I am playing this stream in my app, the visualisation of video is damaged (see screenshot). Does anybody know, what could cause this?[image: damaged video]

EDIT: I realised that this occurs only on the Android 8.1.

Comment: Which player are you using to stream in your APP

Comment: can you past your m3u8 video link

Comment: It was problem of the links, fortunatelly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [library](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) for .m3u8 , this will solve your problem :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:useDefaultControls="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity write below code

```
private VideoView videoView;

private void setupVideoView() {
    // Make sure to use the correct VideoView import
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.m3u8"));
}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
    videoView.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use android studio can impalement [NiceVieoPlayer](https://github.com/xiaoyanger0825/NiceVieoPlayer) library , it powerfull and load on all devices.
you can stream live with it.

its some Chineses :D

goodluck.